# Rest API - I want to filter more then 5000 items in rest API but it is not working properly. here is my code :

Tags: api, rest, sharepoint

function GetListItemByEndPoint(listName, RESTEndPoint, OnSucess, IsNotList) {
var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/" + (IsNotList ? RESTEndPoint : "_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + listName + "')/items" + (RESTEndPoint == "" ? '' : "?" + RESTEndPoint));
jQuery.ajax({
url: url,
type: "GET",
headers: { "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
async: false,
success: function (data) {
OnSucess(data);
},
error: function (xhr, status, error) {
alert("Failed to get Report items.\n" + xhr.responseText);
}
});

}

```
   GetListItemByEndPoint("Daily Inputs", "$select=Category,QueryBalanceb_x002f_f,NormalBalanceb_x002f_f,Received,Processed,Queried,Query_x0020_Resolved,Query_x0020_Balance_x0020_c_x002,Normal_x0020_Balance_x0020_c_x00,Client_x0020_Name/Title,Client_x0020_Name/Id,CSM/Id,CSM/Title,CPT/Id,CPT/Title&$filter=(Created ge datetime'" + StartDate + "T20:00:00.000Z' and Created le datetime'" + EndDate + "T20:00:00.000Z')" + (ClientID == '' ? '' : " and Client_x0020_Name/Id eq " + ClientID) + "  &$expand=Client_x0020_Name,CSM,CPT &$top=5000",
        function (data) {
            BindDashboard(data.d.results, TbaleID, staffId, Btype);
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the limitation of SharePoint REST API, you cannot get more than 5000 items from single API call.

You can use filtering on columns with such conditions that will return less than 5000 items (with first filter condition).

Also, apply indexing on columns you are using in filtering and sorting: [Add an index to a list or library column](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-an-index-to-a-list-or-library-column-f3f00554-b7dc-44d1-a2ed-d477eac463b0)

Check below threads for more information related to this topic:

1. [Rest to read more than 5000 items from document library](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/217254/rest-to-read-more-than-5000-items-from-document-library)
2. [Filtering large list (more than 5K items) using two columns with REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/279965/filtering-large-list-more-than-5k-items-using-two-columns-with-rest-api)
3. [Manage large lists and libraries](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59)

Comment: But still in previous month total data in table is less then 5000 .  around 3000 max.    can wo concate two data object.

Comment: Remove <space> before `$top`. Can you show us the final REST URL generated and used? Are you getting any error? If yes, what is the error message?

Comment: function GetListItemByEndPoint(listName, RESTEndPoint, OnSucess, IsNotList) {
    var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/" + (IsNotList ? RESTEndPoint : "_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + listName + "')/items" + (RESTEndPoint == "" ? '' : "?" + RESTEndPoint));
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,  type: "GET",
        headers: { "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        async: false,                        
        success: function (data) { OnSucess(data); }, error: function (xhr, status, error) {alert("Failed to get Report items.\n" + xhr.responseText);}});}

Comment: Did you try removing space in URL? What is the error message?

Comment: I am asking about the final value of `url` variable (final REST endpoint) and not whole code. What is the `StartDate` value you are using here? Your list should have less than 5000 items created from the StartDate.

Comment: yes, I removed  space in URL.

Comment: can you provide your number and time for meeting foe seeing this in detail.

Answer (score 0):

I have an suggetion for this problem , you can fetch data in parts or bunch like code shown above.

```
const url = "https://{your tanent domain}/sites/{your site name}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listname')/items";
const batchSize = 200; 
let skipCount = 0;
let allItems = [];

async function fetchItems() {
  let hasMoreItems = true;

  while (hasMoreItems) {
    const requestUrl = `${url}?$select=file/ServerRelativeUrl,LinkFilename,*&$filter={Filter string}&$expand=file&$OrderBy=ID asc&$Top=${batchSize}&$Skip=${skipCount}`;

    const response = await fetch(requestUrl, {
      headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata.metadata=minimal",
      }
    });

    const data = await response.json();
    
    allItems = allItems.concat(data.value);

    skipCount += batchSize;

    if (data.value.length < batchSize) {
      hasMoreItems = false;
    }
  }

  // Process allItems array containing all retrieved items
  console.log(allItems);
}

fetchItems();
```

Comment: Based on my experience top and skip can't be applied in queries to objects that contain more than 5000 objects. It will return the same 'The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold.' error.